# How to add Read More Link in Excel Sheet using Asp.net C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I have added read more link option in gridview column and its working perfectly. Now i want to export same gridview data in excel sheet and i want same read more link option in excel sheet as well. After exporting gridview it shows read more in excel but it gives javascript issue.
I searched a lot on internet but didnt get proper solution for this.

Comment: please check this link will help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717086/hyperlinks-not-clickable-when-exported-to-excel .@Kishor Kulkarni

Comment: Thanks for your reply @zahed.. But i dont want to display new page when i click on read more link.  I just want to hide some data while exporting in excel and when you click on read more link it will show all data.

Comment: How exactly are you exporting to Excel?  Show us some code.